# AngularJS - Nav Controller which references $route service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I've been researching, but I can't seem to find the answer that I need.

I'm designing a simple page with AngularJS that has a navigation header. The navigation choices are resolved using a route provider. I cannot specify the controller for my navigation header in my route provider, as I need to reserve this for the controller for my ng-view. I need to be able to set the class of one of my items to 'active' based on a variable 'activeTab' which I have defined in my route provider. My Navigation header is specified by a custom directive.

Currently, the first item loaded is given the active class, but switching between tabs does not change the active tab (it does however change the page shown in ng-view). This indicates that I'm not updating the activeTab variable in my controller correctly, but how would I even go about that?

Here is my code:

index.php

```
<?php 
    include_once('/php/include/check_session.php'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mymapp">
<head>
    <title>My App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav-header></nav-header>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/jquery-dev-3.2.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/aws-sdk.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/include.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.routes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.services.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controller/nav.ctrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/directive/nav.drct.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myapp.routes.js

```
/**
 * 
 */
angular.module('mymapp.routes', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', routes]);

function routes($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'html/template/home.tmpl.html',
            activeTab: 'home'
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            // TODO - Change route to point to check_permissions
            templateUrl: 'html/template/dashboard.tmpl.html',
            activeTab: 'dashboard'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'html/template/contact.tmpl.html',
            activeTab: 'contact'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'html/template/about.tmpl.html',
            activeTab: 'about'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'php/form_login.php',
            activeTab: 'login'
        })
        .when('/logout', {
            templateUrl: 'php/include/logout.php',
            activeTab: 'login'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
}
```

nav.drct.js

```
/**
 * Directive for Displaying a Navigation Header
 */
angular.module('mymapp.core').directive('navHeader', navHeaderDirective);

function navHeaderDirective(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'html/template/nav.tmpl.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'NavController',
        controllerAs: 'navCtrl'
    }
}
```

nav.ctrl.js

```
/**
 * Controller for Nav Header
 */
angular.module('mymapp.core').controller('NavController', [
    '$scope',
    '$route',
    navController
]);

function navController($scope, $route){
    $scope.activeTab = $route.current.activeTab;
}
```

nav.tmpl.html

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#/" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'home' }" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/dashboard" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'dashboard' }" >Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/contact" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'contact' }" >Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/about" ng-class="{ 'active': activeTab == 'about' }" >About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `ng-controller="navCtrl"` to `<div class="navbar" id="navbar">` ?

Comment: I just tried it. Now none of my tabs are displaying the 'active' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use *routeChange* events to listen for changes:

```
function navController($scope, $route){

  updateActiveTab();

  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', updateActiveTab);

  function updateActiveTab(){
     $scope.activeTab = $route.current.activeTab;
  }  

}
```

Currently you are only assigning a primitive which has no inheritance so only gets set once when controller is first run

---

Alternatively if you pass `$route.current` object to the view,  the view would be able to watch changes to it's properties and would get updated during digests:

```
function navController($scope, $route){
  $scope.current = $route.current;
}
```

View

```
<a href="#/" ng-class="{ 'active': current.activeTab == 'home' }" >Home</a>
```

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly. Thank you for the help!